# Array gives me 'Cannot read property of undefined' but console.logs show otherwhise

Tags: javascript, arrays, console

I'm trying to do a method in which i process an array of messages, every message haves an id of the user sending the message and the content of the meesage itself.

Once i get the array, i try to separate the messages by the user who send it (In order to style the messages according to the users later on).

I attempt to do this with a **for loop** to read the array, and an **if** to check if the logged user send such message or not.

The problem pops up when i want to read who send the message.

At first i thought "i may be writing the sentence wrong", so i used some **consol.logs** to see what was wrong. And i got an interesting situation going on: The variable shows correctly on the console, but i get an error once i want to evaluate on the **if**.

Here's the JavaScript code i'm running

```
function processMeesages(allMessages) {

  for (var i = 0; i <= allMessages.length; i++) {

    console.log('allMessages[' + i + '].userMsg', allMessages[i].userMsg)

    //Message from the logged user
    if (allMessages[i].userMsg == user.id) {
      chatMessages += '<div class="row ">' +
              '            <div class="col col-10 "></div>' +
              '            <div class="col card owner-container">' +
              '                <div class="item item-text-wrap owner">' +
                                  allMessages[i].contenido +
              '                </div>' +
              '            </div>' +
              '        </div>';
    }

    //Messages from the other user
    else {
      chatMessages += '<div class="row ">' +
              '            <div class="col card message-container">' +
              '                <div class="item item-text-wrap message">' +
                                  allMessages[i].contenido +
              '                </div>' +
              '            </div>' +
              '            <div class="col col-10 "></div>' +
              '        </div>';
    }
  }

  //Once the for loop ends (What's down didn't show up on the console)
  $rootScope.chatMessages = chatMessages;
  console.log('chatMessages', chatMessages)
  console.log('rootscopeChatMessages', $rootScope.chatMessages)
}
```

[Here's an image with what i get in the console and what the array haves inside (I put some labels on the picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yF2H3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are looping more than required. Your array only has two elements but your for loop tries to loop over 3 times, hence giving that access error because `allMessages[2]` is undefined.

```
function processMeesages(allMessages) {

  for (var i = 0; i < allMessages.length; i++) {

    console.log('allMessages[' + i + '].userMsg', allMessages[i].userMsg)

    .
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks!. I feel so bad now, i've been on this almost an hour now.

Comment: Happens to the best of us. Cheers!